# Nested Rows (Rowspan?) Within ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, html-table

The following image is produced by the following code:

[image]

```
<div class="row" ng-show="result">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Group</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Result</th>
                            <th>Computations</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="r in result | orderBy:'-WarnResult.Value' | filter: { Status: 'warning'}">
                            <td>
                                {
                                <span ng-repeat="(k, v) in r.WarnResult.Group">
                                    {{k}}={{v}}<span ng-hide="$last">,</span>
                                </span>
                                }
                            </td>
                            <td ng-bind="r.Status"></td>
                            <td>
                                <pre ng-bind="json(r.WarnResult.Value)"></pre>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr ng-repeat="c in r.WarnResult.Computations">
                                            <td ng-bind="c.Text"></td>
                                            <td ng-bind="c.Value"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ng-repeat="r in result | orderBy:'-CritResult.Value' | filter: { Status: 'normal'}">
                            <td>
                                {
                                <span ng-repeat="(k, v) in r.CritResult.Group">
                                    {{k}}={{v}}<span ng-hide="$last">,</span>
                                </span>
                                }
                            </td>
                            <td ng-bind="r.Status"></td>
                            <td>
                                <pre ng-bind="json(r.CritResult.Value)"></pre>
                                <pre ng-bind="json(r.WarnResult.Value)"></pre>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr ng-repeat="c in r.CritResult.Computations">
                                            <td ng-bind="c.Text"></td>
                                            <td ng-bind="c.Value"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr ng-repeat="c in r.WarnResult.Computations">
                                            <td ng-bind="c.Text"></td>
                                            <td ng-bind="c.Value"></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I'd like to make it so the the results (The thing in the Pre boxes) lines up with their corresponding computations (The idea is both the WarnResult and CritResult are show when Status is 'normal'). It looks like maybe I want to use rowspan, or maybe something with ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-stop, but I'm having trouble seeing the solution.

Comment: Can you create a simple http://plnkr.co/?

Answer (score 0):

Decided to move the repeat to the tbody, which allows me to have two rows per iteration.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Group</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Expression</th>
            <th>Result</th>
            <th>Computations</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="r in result | orderBy:'-status_number'">
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">
                {
                <span ng-repeat="(k, v) in r.CritResult.Group">
                    {{k}}={{v}}<span ng-hide="$last">,</span>
                </span>
                }
            </td>
            <td rowspan="2" ng-bind="r.Status"></td>
            <td>critical</td>
            <td>
                <pre ng-bind="json(r.CritResult.Value)"></pre>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="c in r.CritResult.Computations">
                            <td ng-bind="c.Text"></td>
                            <td ng-bind="c.Value"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
            <td>warning</td>
            <td>
                <pre ng-bind="json(r.WarnResult.Value)"></pre>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table class="table table-striped table-condensed">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="c in r.WarnResult.Computations">
                            <td ng-bind="c.Text"></td>
                            <td ng-bind="c.Value"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```